# Progress-bar with BlockStack Gaia Storage API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blockchain, gaia, blockstack

I am using React.js to create an app for BlockStack marketplace, which I have a file uploader that upload files to BlockStack Gaia Storage through `putFile` method. This method is a `Promise` is return when a file is uploaded to the server. So, can I add a progress bar? For example, How much data is uploaded yet, percentage?

Comment: Currently not, there is an issue about this for blockstack.js: https://github.com/blockstack/blockstack.js/issues/351